# How to pass data to a SideDrawer in NativeScript?

Tags: nativescript

I created a new App based on the "Drawer Navigation" with NativeScript (project type: TypeScript).

So I am having my SideDrawer defined in app-root.xml, app-root.ts and app-root-view-model.ts.

I am also having a (home) page defined in home-page.xml, home-page.ts and home-view-model.ts.

Now imagine having a button in the home page that does something onTap (e.g. doing a simple calculation). I would like to pass the result of this calculation (e.g. simple integer) to the SideDrawer, so the SideDrawer can show it in a Label.

Currently I have no idea on how to call a method on the SideDrawer from a Page.

Does anybody have a simple sample for me?

Sorry, I am still new to NativeScript and probably not seeing the woods for the trees ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking at the template I believe your root view is RadSideDrawer, so you may simply use `application.getRootView()` to get the RadSideDrawer and access its binding context to update any data.

[Here is a Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=cFBko0) sample.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you :) Coming from an ASP.NET background my main problem is to understand the difference between the page.ts and the view-model.ts. I was under the impression that the page.ts is something like a controller, whereas the view-model.ts is just representing some data. Under no circumstances I would put "real" methods in the model. So, seeing how you did these things with NativeScript helped me al lot! Thank you, Manoj!